# General term of a sequence $u_n=F(n)+G(n)u_{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to know if there is a methode to compute the general term of such a sequence:

Let $x\in(0,1)$.
$u_1=\frac{1}{x}$ and for all $n\geq2$, $u_n=\frac{1}{1-(1-x)^n}+\frac{n-1}{nx}+\frac{n-1}{n}u_{n-1}$.

Comment: Have you tried generating functions? I.e. multiply both sides of the equation for $u_n$ by $y^n$, sum over $n\ge 1$, try to derive a functional relation for the series, solve it to find the closed form, and extract the coefficient of $y^n$. If you do, it looks like the functional relation will involve some integration, so you'll probably have to solve a differential equation along the way.

Comment: Hint: compute $\sum_{1}^{n} k u_k$.

Comment: There may be a simpler way: multipliying both sides by $n$ and summing from $1$ to $N$ we have $u_N=\frac{(N-1)(N-2)}{2Nx}+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{n}{1-(1-x)^n}$. So the question is: is there a closed form solution for $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{n}{1-(1-x)^n}$?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion: try using the general formula you wrote in the title:
\begin{align*}
u_n &= F(n)+G(n)u_{n-1}\\
&= F(n) + G(n)\left[F(n-1)+G(n-1)u_{n-2}\right]\\
&= F(n) + G(n)F(n-1) + G(n)G(n-1)u_{n-2}
\end{align*}
Proceeding in the same way you shoud get something like:
$$
u_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\left[\prod_{h=0}^i G(n-h)\right]F(n-i) + \left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-2} G(n-i)\right]u_1
$$
I believe the terms of the form 
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-2} G(n-i) 
$$
should simplify quite a lot.